# Limit Script to one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script does exactly what I'm looking for with my data, however I'd like to limit it to run only on one sheet. I've tried using `if (s.getName() == 'Sheet1')` immediately after `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]` but then the script no longer functions properly.

What am I missing?

```
function onEdit(e){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = e.range;
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 1) 
    var range2 = range.getRow();
    var destrange = range2;

    // adds the formulas
    var cell = sheet.getRange("C" + destrange);
    cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("details",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH(",",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("details",$B' + destrange +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    var cell = sheet.getRange("D" + destrange);
    cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B' + destrange +',FIND("$",B' + destrange +'),LEN(B' + destrange +'))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    var cell = sheet.getRange("E" + destrange);
    cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("exceed",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH("%",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("exceed",$B' + destrange +')-6),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    var cell = sheet.getRange("F" + destrange);
    cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("due",$B' + destrange +')+3,SEARCH(";",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("due",$B' + destrange +')-3),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    var cell = sheet.getRange("G" + destrange);
    cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("held on",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH(". Lottery",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("held on",$B' + destrange +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    var cell = sheet.getRange("H" + destrange);
    cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("posted by",$B' + destrange +')+9,SEARCH(". ",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("",$B' + destrange +')-167),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to make sure the function acts only on "sheet1"

```
        var range = e.range;
        var sheet = range.getSheet()
        var sheetName = sheet.getName()
        if(sheetName != "Sheet1"){
           return                            //exit function
        }
```

Use event object to get the range>Sheet>SheetName. Compare the sheet name to sheet1 if different exit function

Full code:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet()
    var sheetName = sheet.getName()
    if(sheetName != "Sheet1"){
       return                            //exit function
    }  
    var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
    if (columnOfCellEdited === 1) 
     var range2 = range.getRow();
     var destrange = range2;
     // adds the formulas
     var cell = sheet.getRange("C" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("details",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH(",",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("details",$B' + destrange +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("D" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B' + destrange +',FIND("$",B' + destrange +'),LEN(B' + destrange +'))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("E" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("exceed",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH("%",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("exceed",$B' + destrange +')-6),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("F" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("due",$B' + destrange +')+3,SEARCH(";",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("due",$B' + destrange +')-3),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("G" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("held on",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH(". Lottery",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("held on",$B' + destrange +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("H" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("posted by",$B' + destrange +')+9,SEARCH(". ",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("",$B' + destrange +')-167),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    }

}
```

Hope that helps